Solana Playground airdrop for hello_world not working: "You have requested too many airdrops."
I'm trying to deploy Hello_world on solana playground.
This is my first ever program on solana/devnet.
devnet says I need 0.42 SOL to deploy and to execute "solana airdrop 5" to receive SOL to my wallet.
Every time I execute the code, I get the same error - note I have yet to receive any SOL...
Process error: Client error: You have requested too many airdrops. Wait 24 hours for a refill.
This makes no sense to me because I haven't received any.
I have tried the following changes:

waiting 24 hours
specifying the wallet in the command line
specifying the devnet server in the command line
changing browsers
changing computers
changing networks - even personal hotspot

Last thing to note, I've been following the steps exactly as listed in the hello_world tutorial on solana's website.
Attached is a screenshot.
Please help.  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

This is probably because the rate limit has been reached.
Could you try requesting the airdrop from your local terminal.
Should that fail, check out https://faucet.solana.com/
